# Cannot figure out why the following VBA macro is failing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a drop down list for every cell in a column starting from a specific cell. The following is what I have produced:

```
Public Sub Dropdown()
    Dim dvList As String

    dvList = "Option1, Option2, Option3"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("C25").Resize(50, 1).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula:=dvList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
 End Sub
```

I am having an issue with this line:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula:=dvList
```

When I run this code, I keep getting:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error
```

I don't know why this is happening, it would appear this is the way to do it. Could someone please point out my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it to `Formula1:=dvList`

Comment: +1. Here's [the MSDN reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837441.aspx) You'll also note the absence of a Validation.Formula property.